# angular Routing without Hash

Tags: angular-routing

I want angular routing without hash in Url.
I want Url as http://localhost:56629/Victoria/Home

So Use this Location Provider is  to set Html5 mode true.

But Now the Url Becomes http://localhost:56629/Victoria#%2F/Home. i guess it takes the ascii value of ('/')

But the Controversy is that this (Victoria) is Not static Name. this name is Binding with angular Binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Setting Up the Routings On Server Side, this problem is solved